# Using LIME for predictions of a logit model in R?

Tags: r, glm, lime

So I am trying to use LIME to understand predictions from a logit model in R. I know I don't 'need' to, but I am trying to illustrate what it does with a model that one can simply understand as a starting point for a presentation.

But I am having troubles getting this working. I am sure it is due to the model.predict aspect, but my few solutions have not worked.

Basically here is what I would like to do:

```
model.logit <- glm(formula = formula, data = build.dat, family = binomial(link = "logit"))


train.x <- build.dat[ , all.vars(formula[[3]])] 
test.x <- reject.dat[1:100, all.vars(formula[[3]])]

explainer <- lime(train.x, as_classifier(model.logit ), n_bins = 20, quantile_bins = TRUE)

explain.me <- lime::explain(test.x[2 , ], explainer, n_labels = 1, n_features = 8, n_permutations = 5000, 
                        feature_select = "forward_selection", type = "response" )
```

Now I get the error

```
Error in match.arg(type) :'arg' should be one of “link”, “response”, “terms”
```

But moving my 'type = "response"' within the 'lime' code does not fix it.

And I have tried creating a function 'predict_model.glm' with what I thought might correct this due to what I thought was going on when I was using randomForest and got it working:

```
predict_model.glm <- function(x, newdata, type = "response" ) {
res <- as.data.frame(c(predict(x, newdata = newdata, type = type), 1-predict(x, newdata = newdata, type = type)))

}
```

But this only seemed to add errors.

I am sure this is due to my missing what exactly the 'lime' aspect is looking for (thus my failure at correcting this with the 'predict_model.glm' function), but I cannot seem to find clarification anywhere.

Any help would be great, Thanks!

Comment: So an update. I found this error was resolved if I directly called 'type = "response" ' inside the function 'predict_model.glm

Comment: However, now the internally used glm.fit function does not seem to like my predictions and I get:

Comment: Error in glm.fit(x = x_fit, y = y, weights = weights, family = gaussian()) : 
  NAs in V(mu) . I have tried addressing this by changing the format of the output in the data frame within 'predict_model.glm' but cannot seem to fix this. And I do have a 'model_type.glm <- function(x,...) 'classification' call in there

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to transform the output of predict within `predict_model.glm`. As a first step, I'd recomment printing `type` and one first row of the result of calling `predict`. Depending on the type passed in, the call to glm and the returned result will be different - `?predict_model` hints at it: for 'raw', it's a single res, for 'prob', it's probabilities (or for really linear model: the numeric result).

Overall, as far as I (hopefully) understand your case, a function similar to that one might get you one step forward:

```
predict_model.glm <- function(x, newdata, type, ...) { 
  print(type)
  res <- predict(x, newdata);
  print(res[1])
  data.frame(Response = res)
}
```